# SharePoint PnP - Adding fields to default view

Tags: sharepoint-2016

I’m using the SharePoint PnP templates to deploy a list instance to SharePoint 2016. Is it possible to make the field “TheName” part of the default view or a particular view using an attribute?

Below I’ve set the “TheName” field attributes Viewable="true" ShowInDisplayForm="true" ShowInViewForms="true" but that has not resulted in “TheName” being part of the default view. Below is the xml for the list instance:

```
             <pnp:ListInstance Title="Application" Description="" EnableAttachments="true" DocumentTemplate="" TemplateType="100" Url="Lists/Application" MinorVersionLimit="0" MaxVersionLimit="0" DraftVersionVisibility="0" TemplateFeatureID="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" ContentTypesEnabled="true" EnableFolderCreation="true">

                <pnp:ContentTypeBindings>

                    <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x0109413FF39DA2049E08C8B9564402E3562" Default="true" />

                </pnp:ContentTypeBindings>

                    <pnp:Fields>

                    <pnp:Field Type="Text" DisplayName="TheName" StaticName="TheName" Name="TheName" Default="true" ID="{db2beb10-5325-434d-a559-691e340a4fea}" Viewable="true" ShowInDisplayForm="true" ShowInViewForms="true" />

                    </pnp:Fields>

                </pnp:Views>

            </pnp:ListInstance>
```

I can explicitly create/set the default view to include “TheName” but then I end up having to list all the fields that are part of the list including the ones which come from a site content type. This can become a hassle to maintain. The below list instance xml displays “TheName” as part of the default view:

```
             <pnp:ListInstance Title="Application" Description="" EnableAttachments="true" DocumentTemplate="" TemplateType="100" Url="Lists/Application" MinorVersionLimit="0" MaxVersionLimit="0" DraftVersionVisibility="0" TemplateFeatureID="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" ContentTypesEnabled="true" EnableFolderCreation="true">

                <pnp:ContentTypeBindings>

                    <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x0109413FF39DA2049E08C8B9564402E3562" Default="true" />

                </pnp:ContentTypeBindings>

                    <pnp:Fields>

                    <pnp:Field Type="Text" DisplayName="TheName" StaticName="TheName" Name="TheName" Default="true" ID="{db2beb10-5325-434d-a559-691e340a4fea}" Viewable="true" ShowInDisplayForm="true" ShowInViewForms="true" />

                    </pnp:Fields>

                    <pnp:Views>

                    <View DisplayName="All Items">

                    <ViewFields>

                        <FieldRef Name="TheName" />

                        <FieldRef Name="Title" />

                        <FieldRef Name="ApplicationId" />

                        <FieldRef Name="Case" />

                    </ViewFields>

                    </View>

                </pnp:Views>

            </pnp:ListInstance>
```